# Avoiding "Pure Virtual Function Call" in Derived Class C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual

I'm reasonably new to C++ so I'd like to apologize if the level of this question is a little below the usual standards here -

I'm trying to get several classes to inherit from a base class which has a virtual function definition, then I'd like to create an array of MainClass* which can include all of the derived classes in order to output the derived + defined virtual function.

I receive the Error "R6025: pure virtual function call" - I don't know why, I was assuming that - when called - the updated definition of that function from the child classes was used.

Here's my code:

Base:

```
class mitarbeiter
{
public:
    mitarbeiter(string name, int nummer);
    ~mitarbeiter(void);
    virtual void einkommen() = 0;
protected:
    string name;
    int nummer;

};
```

Derived1:

```
#include "mitarbeiter.h"
class lohnempfaenger : public mitarbeiter
{
public:
    lohnempfaenger(int stundenlohn, int anzahlStunden, string name, int nummer);
    ~lohnempfaenger(void);
    void einkommen();
private:
    int stundenlohn;
    int anzahlStunden;
};
```

Derived 2:

```
#include "mitarbeiter.h"
#include <string>
class angestellter : public mitarbeiter
{
public:
    angestellter(int gehalt, string name, int nummer);
    ~angestellter(void);
    void einkommen();
private:
    int gehalt;
};
```

Implementation of "einkommen()" in Derived 1:

```
void lohnempfaenger::einkommen()
{
    cout << "Lohnempfaenger, Name: " << this->name << ", Gesamtlohn: " << this->stundenlohn*this->anzahlStunden << "\n";
}
```

Implementation of "einkommen()" in Derived 2:

```
void angestellter::einkommen()
{
    cout << "Angestellter, Name: " << this->name << ", Einkommen: " << this->gehalt << "\n";
}
```

Array-Declaration in main method:

```
mitarbeiter* mitPtr[5];
mitPtr[0] = &angestellter(/*values...*/);
//error
mitPtr[0]->einkommen();
```

Constructors:

```
mitarbeiter::mitarbeiter(string name, int nummer)
{
    this->name = name;
    this->nummer = nummer;
}

angestellter::angestellter(int gehalt, string name, int nummer):mitarbeiter(name, nummer)
{
    this->gehalt = gehalt;
}

lohnempfaenger::lohnempfaenger(int stundenlohn, int anzahlStunden, string name, int nummer):mitarbeiter(name, nummer)
{
    this->stundenlohn = stundenlohn;
    this->anzahlStunden = anzahlStunden;
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you try to put together a self-contained example file that we can compile in a single step?

Comment: void angestellter::einkommen(); should be declared virtual

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but the destructor of `mitarbeiter` should be `virtual`, otherwise you'll get Udefined Behaviour if you ever `delete` a derived instance through a pointer to `mitarbeiter`.

Comment: @jbh: that won't matter, as only the base must be declared virtual.

Comment: @jbh: That's optional; it's implicitly virtual since it overrides `mitarbeiter::einkommen()`.

Comment: I am confused that you show the implementation of `lohnempfaenger::einkommen()`, but use `new angestellter`. Do you have an implementation of `angestellter::einkommen()`?

Comment: I'm not calling "einkommen" anywhere else in the code. If I use it "normally", that is e.g. by creating a new instance of Angestellter and then calling einkommen, it works fine.

I'll try to work on the self-contained example now.

Comment: @JohnZwinck You are right, I misread the code

Comment: If you ever see a "pure virtual function called" kind of termination, that means that your program is broken. It's not just a matter of forgetting to override a pure virtual or to define the override; those would be compile and link errors, respectively, not runtime errors.

Comment: I've just created the self-contained example ... "unfortunately" it works. I was assuming I'd done it in the same fashion I have here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Now you've shown us how you actually initialise the pointer, here is the problem:

```
mitPtr[0] = &angestellter(/*values...*/);
```

That points to a temporary object, which is destroyed at the end of the statement. Using the pointer afterwards will give undefined behaviour.

You'll need a non-temporary variable to point to:

```
angestellter a(/*values...*/);
mitPtr[0] = &a;
```

or perhaps a dynamically allocated object:

```
mitPtr[0] = new angestellter(...);
```

In that case, don't forget to delete it; and don't forget to give the base class a virtual destructor so it can be deleted. You might consider using a smart pointer to delete it for you; `std::unique_ptr` would be ideal.

Comment: Ahh, I understand - I never thought that could have an effect on it - thanks!

Comment: @Dennis For the record, the reason you're getting "pure virtual called" is because when a destructor is called, it resets the class's vtable to the next one down. So, when `~angestellter` was called, it reset the class's functions to those of `mitarbeiter` - this is why you'd get the same problem if you tried to call `einkommen()` in `~angestellter`. So you're accessing invalid memory when you call `einkommen()`, but the memory probably still contains its last-valid contents, which was the pointer to the pure marker in the base class.

Answer (score 0):

The error message, which I'm guessing you see at run time, is saying that mitarbeiter::einkommen() is being called.

Your main code claims to be allocating a new angestellter, whose code you did not provide, but there are several possible places that the call could be hiding.

If mitarbeiter::mitarbeiter calls einkommen(), you will get mitarbeiter::einkommen() no matter what type you specified to new. This seems the most likely place.

The other possibilities are explicit calls to the fully qualified mitarbeiter::einkommen() in either angestellter::angestellter() or angestellter::einkommen().