# Pure virtual method called error and crash

Tags: c++, virtual

Yet again "Pure virtual method called error", I checked other similar question, they do not resolve my issue.
I have a crash with the mentioned message. I don't do any fancy staff. The code is big, so only the important extracts:

```
class cCOLLECT_STR_NODES_HELPER
{
  protected:
    cCOLLECT_STR_NODES_HELPER( const std::string& searchStr,
                           const int attribute,
               const cGTI_SRCH_TREE_NAME_DLG *pDlg )
   : m_compareStr(searchStr), m_attr(attribute), pSrchDlg(pDlg) {}

    virtual ~cCOLLECT_STR_NODES_HELPER() {}

   public:
    virtual bool TreatTheNode( const cGTC_TREE_NODE *curNode ) = 0;
...
}
```

Then goes derived class:

```
class cCOLLECT_STR_TOP_NODES_HELPER : public cCOLLECT_STR_NODES_HELPER
{
  public:
   cCOLLECT_STR_TOP_NODES_HELPER( const std::string& searchStr,
                               const int attribute,
                   const cGTI_SRCH_TREE_NAME_DLG *pDlg )
   : cCOLLECT_STR_NODES_HELPER( searchStr, attribute, pDlg ) {}

public:
virtual bool TreatTheNode( const cGTC_TREE_NODE *curNode );
...
}
```

TreatTheNode() is implemented separately:

```
bool cCOLLECT_STR_TOP_NODES_HELPER::TreatTheNode( const cGTC_TREE_NODE *curNode ) {...
```

Then derived class initialized:

```
cCOLLECT_STR_NODES_HELPER *pHelper;

  cCOLLECT_STR_TOP_NODES_HELPER helper( searchStr, attribute, this );
  pHelper = &helper;
```

Then pHelper passed into a function and used there:

```
TraverseTreeNodes( const cGTC_TREE_NODE *curNode,
               cCOLLECT_STR_NODES_HELPER *pHelper ) const
{
if ( pHelper->TreatTheNode( curNode ) )  => CRASH
```

The project built successfully. What's wrong?

Comment: What compiler are you using?  I'm suspecting pHelper is null and that's what's blowing up...

Comment: @Nathan Monteleone Sorry, found an error from side. No, it's not null.

Comment: `The project built successfully.` Sigh. Why do so many persons asking a question bring up this line? Just because your project builds ok doesn't mean it will run ok. Second, what debugging have you done?  Third, because your program is large, that is more of a reason to believe your issues started with the code you didn't post.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie The project being built is an additional info which should be added, otherwise people would ask for it. It's obvious that doesn't mean project will run ok, that's why I asked the question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I found a mistake from my side and deleted the question, I decided to undelete and partially answer it. I am sure somebody else can benefit from this stupid mistake (when you have a deadline in 3 hours you do make mistakes).

I knew it was something obvious: actually the code which I wrote as:

```
cCOLLECT_STR_TOP_NODES_HELPER helper( searchStr, attribute, this );
pHelper = &helper;
```

in reality was:

```
{
  cCOLLECT_STR_TOP_NODES_HELPER helper( searchStr, attribute, this );
  pHelper = &helper;
}
```

so helper went out of scope...

The problem is, I did debugging. pHelper was pointing to something meaningful, at least
that's what it looked like. I am still not sure how exactly the crash happened, but the
reason is clear. When the pointed object went out of scope, it is probably UB. 
Still, if somebody describes what internally happened, I'll accept the answer.

Comment: An accepted answer in: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20146111/avoiding-pure-virtual-function-call-in-derived-class-c?rq=1 
confirms UB.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you are facing a null pointer problem, as you are passing a uninitialized object into the arguments, the pHelper would not have a value, thus will attempt to crash the program.

Comment: pHelper is initialized: pHelper = &helper; it's obviously not null.

Comment: whoops, i didn't see that.